# How to implement filters feature for postgres database with sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have a database for movies(like imdb), which stores information about movies in tables. This is the Schemas for the tables in this database.

```
Movie.model- movieId, title, genre
Link.model- movieId, imdblink,....
Tag.model- movieId, tag, timestamp
Rating.model- movieId, rating,...
```

I have figured out how to find movies in comedy genre by using the findAll(where:(genre:comedy))
and can find all movies with rating>4. However I cant find movies which have rating more than 4, in the comedy genre released between 2011 and 2013.

I have tried to use commands like next(); but it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Adding code-

Here are my models-

model.movie

```
Const Movie = sequelize.define('movie', {
    movieid: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primarykey:true,
      allowNull: true
    },
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    genre: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    }
  },{timestamps: false});
```

model.rating

```
const Rating= sequelize.define('rating', {
    userid: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    movieid: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    rating: {
      type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    timestamp: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    }
  },{timestamps: false});
```

Adding relationship

```
Movie.associate=function(){
    Movie.hasMany(Rating),{
        foreignKey:'movieid',
        as:'movies'
    }
}
Rating.belongsTo(Movie);
```

I'm trying to find Movies by their rating so I'm trying out this code-

```
Movie.findAll({
    include:{
        model:Rating,
        where:{
            rating:4
        },
        required:false
    }
})
```

I get the following error-

```
SequelizeEagerLoadingError: rating is not associated to movie!
```

Comment: Take a look at the examples on the `findAll` [docs page](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll).

Comment: Just did, didn't find anything that would solve my problem. Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing any of your code. Can you post a snippet of what you think your problematic code is?

Comment: Added code in the question